# Initial conditions for this LC-Circuit

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, inductor, passive-networks

I have an upcoming exam in a few days so I'm going trough some problems I found online or in textbooks and just try to solve them.

I have one here where I'm not entirely sure about the initial conditions of the problem and I hoped that maybe someone could help me out a little bit.

**The circuit:**

[image]

**The problem:**

A LC circuit is driven a long time with constant current \$I_0\$ (switch closed). At \$t=0\$ the current gets switched off (switch off). What are the currents and voltages on the capacitor and on the inductor for \$t=0^+\$? Calculate the voltage on the capactior for\$t\gt0\$.

So basically I have to find the inital conditions for the differential equation I have to setup for the next question where the voltage of the capacitor is asked.

My though process was: Before the switch is openend: $$I_L(0^-)=I_0$$ $$U_C(0^-)=U_0$$ 
Since \$U_C\$ and \$I_L\$ are continuous it should follow that $$I_L(0^+)=I_0$$ $$U_C(0^+)=U_0$$The thing I'm unsure about are now \$U_L(0^+)\$ and \$I_C(0^+)\$ . My guess would be that $$I_C(0^+)=-I_0?$$ $$U_L(0^+)=-U_0$$ since KVL says that \$U_C+U_L=0\$.

Sadly there are no solutions avaiable so I don't know if I'm doing the right thing here, it would be great if someone could give me a hint or an advice on how to tackle this problem correctly.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the voltage across an inductor when the current through the inductor is not changing?  That will help you determine the correct voltage across the capacitor before the switch is opened (U0).

Comment: The answers are all over the internet with the "right" keywords on LC resonance.  But for fun I made you a simulation.  https://tinyurl.com/y83xvh6v

Comment: Thanks for the simulation! 
Well the voltage across the inductor before the switch is opened should be zero then. Does this mean that the voltage across the capacitor is also zero before the switch is closed since this is a paralell circuit?

Comment: If components are in parallel and one of them has 0 volts across it then......

Comment: Well, then the other component should also have 0 volts across it, right? Sry, maybe I just have a big thought error right now...